# CSS/JS: split words with horizontal line in responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

What would be the best way to split a word in the middle (or after a specific amount of characters or syllables) and join both "word-parts" with a line. Basically imagine a very long flexible underscore.

The goal is to have "word___part" always 100% of the parent container. 
Meaning it should work fully responsive when scaling down or up the browser-window.

```css
    span:first-child {
     float:left;
     display:inline-block;
    }
    
    span.underscore {
    
    }
    
    span:last-child {
     float:right;
     display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <span>Auto</span><span class="underscore"></span><span>mation</span>
```

How would you approach that? Flexbox?

*Additionally the meta-goal would even be to set the word that is split apart with a dynamic-cms. Meaning the word "Automation" comes from a backend.*

Comment: Have you *tried* building it with flexbox? Seems like the right tool, and you've identified it above...

Comment: no, couldn't think of how to do this with flexbox as I'm pretty new to flexbox.

Comment: Apply `border-bottom` to `.underscore` along with `flex-grow: 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element on first `span` element and set `align-items: flex-end;` to align line at bottom of spans.

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}
span:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}
span:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Auto</span><span>mation</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor </span><span>sit.</span>
</div>
```

You can also use js to split string at specific word and wrap each part in `span` elements.

```js
function modify(selector, word) {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  var text = el.textContent;
  var i = text.indexOf(word)

  if (i != -1) {
    var arr = [text.substring(0, i), text.substring(i)]
    el.innerHTML = arr.map(e => '<span>' + e + '</span>').join('');
  }
}

modify('.e1', 'mation')
modify('.e2', 'sit')
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}
span:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}
span:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="e1">Automation</div>
<div class="e2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `border-bottom` to `.underscore` along with `flex-grow: 1`, then adjust height and margins to fit.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

span.underscore {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Auto</span><span class="underscore"></span><span>mation</span>
</div>
```

You can even use a `dotted` border instead of `solid` to simulate ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way:

```
<div>
  <span class="left">Auto</span>
  <span class="underscore"></span>
  <span class="right">mation</span>
</div>

div {
  display: flex;
}

.underscore {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaddqO

Answer (score 0):

In case if `background-color` behind text element is a solid color:

1. Create `background-image` with `linear-gradient()` on parent.
2. Override `background-color` on child elements.

**Working Demo:**

```css
.text {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 5px, black 5px,
                                      black 7px, transparent 7px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.text span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span>Auto</span>
  <span>mation</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are good but you said ***Additionally the meta-goal would even be to set the word that is split apart with a dynamic-cms. Meaning the word "Automation" comes from a backend.***
So yiu can use the getword() method to get the word from backend and separate it into two using javascript

You can try to run the snippet and see the output. Then change the string returned by the getword() method and run again.

```js
 var container = document.getElementById('slit-container');
 var word = getWord();
 var wordPartOne = word.substring(0, 4);
 var wordPartTwo = word.substring(4, word.lenght);
 var data = "<span>"+wordPartOne+"</span> <span>"+wordPartTwo+"</span>";
 container.innerHTML = data;

 function getWord(){
   //Query your backend to get the word
   //for test purpose I will just return a string

   return "Automation"
 }
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}
span:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}
span:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="slit-container">

</div>
```